# CSS, IE7... how to not move down the content

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've some issues with IE 7, could you please tell me how to avoid my content to shift down when I move the mouse over Contact (under the title)

http://www.lancelmaat.nl/drupal/index.php?q=allwork

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved by moving the contact div at the bottom of the page. In this way it has not other divs after him, that are shifted by IE6 and 7.

But this solution is not generalizing well for other websites.

Answer (score 0):

the hover-menue of "contact" is higher than the rest of the site. one possibility you could try is setting `height:100%` on your `body` and `html`.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see I feel that the `<p>` creates extra padding.
Try `<div>` instead of `<p>` or try `<p style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">` in

```
<p>KAREN LANCEL:<br />
lancel(at)xs4all.nl<br />
phone 0031 (0)624873424</p>
```

Just a suggestion to try.

Comment: ok thanks. I've added (and then removed) #block-block-1 p { margin:0px; padding:0px;} but it didn't work. Same issue. Furthermore, I want to keep the padding, because I want the paragraphes be separated.

Comment: well, i didn't mean it for all P elements, just for the first one, but if it didn't work, my other suggestion (because it is only observed in IE) is to remove the whitespace between the div and the p in <div class="content"><p>KAREN LANCEL

Comment: don't underestimate whitespace, this might sound silly, but occasionally it does break presentation, and not just in IE

Comment: well I've removed the whitespace with  $('#block-block-1 .content').text($('#block-block-1 .content').text().replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,''));
 but still it is sliding down

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is actually `position: absolute`

This will pull the element out of the normal flow of the document, and make it so the layout won't be affected by its display. From there, position the container with `left: (px)`, and `top: (px)`, or with margins.

Comment: it is already set (position:absolute), but in IE 6 and 7, the position of the following elements, is still influenced. (if you switch between display:none, display:block for example when you move the mouse over